# Are there any ways to get SQL queries by transaction id or process in PostgreSQL log?

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

I'm trying to resolve some deadlocks, occuring in my production PostgreSQL server. What I have:

1. Sentry, showing first locking query (process 2840554 in log below)
2. PostgreSQL deadlock message in logs:

```
2022-05-24 21:48:52 MSK [2840554-1] carrotquest@carrot_shard_1 LOG:  process 2840554 detected deadlock while waiting for ShareLock on transaction 4153893838 after 1000.029 ms
2022-05-24 21:48:52 MSK [2840554-2] carrotquest@carrot_shard_1 DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 2879765. Wait queue: .
2022-05-24 21:48:52 MSK [2840554-3] carrotquest@carrot_shard_1 CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (72609310,2) in relation "users_user"
2022-05-24 21:48:52 MSK [2840554-4] carrotquest@carrot_shard_1 STATEMENT:  SELECT "users_user"."id", "users_user"."app_id", "users_user"."props_json", "users_user"."props_events_json", "users_user"."removed", "users_user"."hidden", "users_user"."email_status_id", "users_user"."es_index" FROM "users_user" WHERE "users_user"."id" = 1138071193757156022 LIMIT 21 FOR UPDATE
2022-05-24 21:48:52 MSK [2879765-2] carrotquest@carrot_shard_1 DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 2840554. Wait queue: 2879765, 2883036.
2022-05-24 21:48:52 MSK [2840554-5] carrotquest@carrot_shard_1 ERROR:  deadlock detected
2022-05-24 21:48:52 MSK [2840554-6] carrotquest@carrot_shard_1 DETAIL:  Process 2840554 waits for ShareLock on transaction 4153893838; blocked by process 2879765.
     Process 2879765 waits for ShareLock on transaction 4153893850; blocked by process 2840554.
     Process 2840554: SELECT "users_user"."id", "users_user"."app_id", "users_user"."props_json", "users_user"."props_events_json", "users_user"."removed", "users_user"."hidden", "users_user"."email_status_id", "users_user"."es_index>
     Process 2879765: COMMIT

2022-05-24 21:48:52 MSK [2840554-7] carrotquest@carrot_shard_1 HINT:  See server log for query details.
2022-05-24 21:48:52 MSK [2840554-8] carrotquest@carrot_shard_1 CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (72609310,2) in relation "users_user"
2022-05-24 21:48:52 MSK [2840554-9] carrotquest@carrot_shard_1 STATEMENT:  SELECT "users_user"."id", "users_user"."app_id", "users_user"."props_json", "users_user"."props_events_json", "users_user"."removed", "users_user"."hidden", "users_user"."email_status_id", "users_user"."es_index" FROM "users_user" WHERE "users_user"."id" = 1138071193757156022 LIMIT 21 FOR UPDATE
```

As you see second process holding the lock is unknown - it is some transaction performing "COMMIT;" blocking transaction 4153893838.

My question is: Is threre a way to find some information about this transaction? SQL, or some other clues which can help me find it in my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `%x` to your `log_line_prefix`, then the transaction ID will be logged too. If you log all statements, you can then easily identify all statements that belong to that transaction.

I know it may not be feasible to log everything, but that's the only way to do that in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I understand that way though it is really impossible for me to log everything as it is high loaded production database

Comment: And does this id correspond to `SELECT txid_current()`? I think of logging some data with transaction id inside my app instead of logging all PG queries, but I need some matching value

Comment: That would be `pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned()` (or `txid_current_if_assigned()` in older releases). `txid_current()` will *create* a transaction ID if there is none yet, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A time has passed and I also found a beautiful way to debug where the problem is. I add a comment to end of each query like `SELECT something FROM somewhere; /* file/view.py function():10 */`. So I can easily find where problematic queries come from.

P. s. In my case I use [Django python framework](https://www.djangoproject.com/). So I decorated `django.db.utils.ConnectionHandler.create_connection`. After modification, this method automatically adds `conn.execute_wrappers` to each connection. Wrapper adds tag to sql using `traceback.extract_stack()` results.